# How to add an element with jQuery with after() or append(), only if the element isn't already present

Tags: jquery

I want to run the following jQuery

```
$('.existing-element').after('<div class="new-element"></div>');
```

but only if the element "new-element" doesn't already exist there. In other words, I'm trying to prevent the jQuery above from adding that element multiple times.

I'm looking to add the element in my header (next to my business logo)

Comment: You're right, I should've included the part about the element going into my header, instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the new element already exists, check the `length` property:

```
if( !$('div.new-element').length ) $('.existing-element').after('<div class="new-element"></div>');
```

If the div already exists, the length will be greater than zero.

Comment: Of course, that looks globally in the document, rather than in the location the OP is targeting.

Comment: Actually, this works for me because I'm adding the element in my header, next to my logo

Answer (score 1):

If there will only ever be one `.existing-element`, you can test to find out if it already has `.new-element` just after it via [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next) and [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass):

```
var $el = $(".existing-element");
if (!$el.next().hasClass("new-element")) {
    $el.after('<div class="new-element"></div>');
}
```

If there are several `.exiting-element`s in the document, you'll need to either use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each) or [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter). With `each`:

```
$(".existing-element").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if (!$el.next().hasClass("new-element")) {
        $el.after('<div class="new-element"></div>');
    }
});
```

With `filter`:

```
$(".existing-element").filter(functino() {
    return !$(this).next().hasClass("new-element");
}).after('<div class="new-element"></div>');
```

---

Note about `.next().hasClass("new-element")`: It works just fine even if there is no next element. In that case, `.next()` will return an empty jQuery set, and `hasClass` will always return false.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough response, works just as you described